# How to choose seaborn boxplots color by hue

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to know how can I choose the color for a seaborn boxplot by hue.

The current box plots I have
[image: Current box plots]

For example, I want to use RGB colors, blue for left, red for right.

```
sns.boxplot(x="S", y="data", hue="Side", data=dataset, showfliers=True)
```

### Solved

Following Alex's comment and added `palette={"left": "blue", "right": "red"}` to the plot command I was able to solve the issue. If someone came here looking for the solution you can also check http://latexcolor.com/ and choose the color you want just by copying the value from the **hex** column instead of the color name.

Comment: add `palette={"left": "blue", "right": "red"}` when you create the box plot.

Comment: Thanks a lot, That solved the issue

Comment: Matplotlib (and seaborn) uses [web color names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors).  Additionally, there is a long list of [named xkcd colors](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colors.html#xkcd-colors)